# Programmatically populating html table cells

Tags: c#, html, loops, sharepoint, html-table

I would like to loop through a table that I created using C# code and display data pulled from a Sharepoint list which was formatted in a table. This is the code I came up with:

```
    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        try
        {
            SPSite thisSite = SPControl.GetContextSite(Context);
            using (SPWeb topWeb = thisSite.OpenWeb("/"))
            {
                SPList newsList = topWeb.Lists["Headlines"];
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.ExpandRecurrence = true;
                query.Query = NewsListCamlQuery;
                query.RowLimit = 2;
                SPListItemCollection coll = newsList.GetItems(query);

                output.Write("<table border='0' style='width: 100%;'><tbody>");

                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    output.Write("<tr>");

                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        output.Write("<td>");

                        foreach (SPListItem item in coll)
                        {
                            int newsID = int.Parse(item.ID.ToString());

                            output.Write("<hr/>");
                            output.Write("<table style='width: 100%; height: 143px;'><tbody>");
                            output.Write("<tr><td valign='top'><h4>");
                            output.Write(item["Title"].ToString());
                            output.Write("</h4></td></tr>");
                            output.Write("<tr><td valign='top'><h4 class='ms-rteElement-H4B'><span style='font-size: 8pt;'>");
                            output.Write(item["Sub_x0020_Heading"].ToString());
                            output.Write("</span></h4></td></tr>");
                            output.Write("<tr><td valign='top'><span style='font-size: 8pt;'>");
                            output.Write("<img class='image' src='");
                            //output.Write(item["Photo"].ToString());
                            output.Write("' Width='64px' Height='48px' Border='0' alt='' style='margin: 5px;'/>");
                            output.Write(item["Details"].ToString());
                            output.Write("</span></td></tr>");
                            output.Write("<tr><td valign='top'>");
                            output.Write("<a class='mt-linkMore' href='/Lists/Headlines/DispForm.aspx?ID=");
                            output.Write(newsID);
                            output.Write("' <span style='font-size: 6pt;'>Read More</span></a></td></tr>");
                            output.Write("</tbody></table>");
                        }

                        output.Write("</td>");
                    }

                    output.Write("</tr>");
                }

                output.Write("</tbody></table>");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            output.Write("Error : " + exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

This code is currently re-writing the same record in each cell. I would like for it to display the six records that is being pulled from the Sharepoint list.

Comment: The simplest solution to debug is to write all the html in a string and when you have completed the loop copy the data from string and paste it in a html file (text file saved as html). Then see the html and you will find where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display two lines of 3 cells, you should not put the foreach.

On the inside of the second loop, you can make reference directly to the element of your list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    output.Write("<tr>");

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        output.Write("<td>");

        int index;
        if (i = 0)
            index = j;
        else
            index = j + 3;

        SPListItem item = coll[index];
        int newsID = int.Parse(item.ID.ToString());
        ...
```

Comment: Where in my code should I place this line of code. Also will this allow me to retieve the last 6 rows of a sharepoint list.